# Position a button (of Twitter Digits) programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, layout, twitter-digits

a newbie question :)

I'm trying to use [Twiiter Digits](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html) for authentication (by phone number) in my (first) iOS app.

It is easier for my to understand how to position a button programatically when it is a button that i create. but this 1 line of code confuses me.

to embed their action button i just need to add this part of code ([see documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html)):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let digitsButton = DGTAuthenticateButton(authenticationCompletion: { (session, error) in
        // Inspect session/error objects
    })
    self.view.addSubview(digitsButton)
}
```

My problem is that the creation of this button is automatically and have a completion handler, so when\where exactly do i have the option to position (format) it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create your own custom button and use the methods of Digits to perform the same actions. For example :

```
func didTapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let digits = Digits.sharedInstance()
    digits.authenticateWithCompletion { (session, error) in
        // Inspect session/error objects
    }
}
```

Also if you want to continue to customize your Digits button and it's View Controllers , you can find more here [here](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/digits/features).

Answer (score 0):

It might sound strange but it took me some time to realize i can\need to do it after the completion handler (inside the ViewDidLoad...).

Thanks for Letting me know i can use my own button with Digits.